# Generating AAR file from third party library Android

Tags: android, android-library, arr

I am looking to create an AAR file from an existing third party android library but have so far been unable to find much documentation online. One post mentioned that the file is automatically generated when you add the library as a dependency to an existing Android Studio project and build that project, another said to use Apache Axis2. Still though, im having trouble generating it. If anyone could give advice or point me in the right direction that would be great. (P.S apologies if this is a noob question) Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are using Gradle?  If so, what does your settings.gradle and build.gradle look like?

Comment: Have you got any solution for this yet?